# How to install rvm on Vagrant (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) using Puppet?

Tags: rvm, puppet, vagrant, ubuntu-12.04

I have a Vagrant base box running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin). I can bring up the box (`vagrant up`)  and ssh (`vagrant ssh`) into it fine.

Next step: I want to use Puppet to provision RVM and Ruby 1.9.3-p125.

I used the puppet-rvm module from: https://github.com/blt04/puppet-rvm

I followed the instructions and added the following to my Puppet manifest:

```
include rvm
rvm_system_ruby {
  'ruby-1.9.3-p125':
    ensure => present,
    default_use => true;
}
```

Then I destroyed my VM (`vagrant destroy`) and recreated it (`vagrant up`) expecting Puppet to install RVM.

But when I ssh into the VM there's no rvm for me :(

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Is there any information I can provide that might help figure this out?

Comment: You can spare a few minutes instead of the cycle up-destroy, launch `vagrant provision`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the [puppet-rvm module](https://github.com/blt04/puppet-rvm), you can run into problems if you set `default_use => true` because puppet may not be available to the Ruby you just installed. The puppet-rvm module is installed system-wide, so you need to make sure that root's Ruby is the system Ruby to avoid breakage.

Comment: Thanks, that did seem to do the trick. In addition, I added `rvm::define::user` to my manifest with the 'vagrant' user I use to login.

Comment: this one looks more active https://github.com/maestrodev/puppet-rvm a sample installation http://blog.csanchez.org/2014/01/14/installing-rvm-and-multiple-ruby-versions-with-puppet/

Answer (score 0):

for vagrant you could build a box with RVM already installed, just use veewee and this definition: 
https://github.com/mpapis/rvm-test-vagrant/tree/master/definitions/rvm-ubuntu-12.04-amd64

I was building it yesterday and it worked all fine.

Comment: Thanks. I did manage to build a base box with rvm installed. However, the requirement was that the base box should be a "clean" install of Ubuntu and all "extras" should be provisioned through Puppet.